# No element found for selector: #react-select-17-option-0 (dropdown menu)

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to select a dropdown menu from a page but unable to select one of the options using puppetteer. I have checked the element selector. the page is only 1 frame this is the html source code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12co5.png)

When I click on await page.click('input[id="react-select-7-input"]') I get the dropdown in a screenshot but in the html instead of the value of the input being changed it adds a div with "Regular Passport" which is option 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYEY8.png)

Comment: let me add some info here. I can see an input with an "Id react-select-7-input" when I inspect the webpage but the document.querySelector does not find it,,,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your HTML and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: I would try it like `[id="react-select-17-option-0"]` because I'm not sure dashes are allowed with `#`.

Comment: I tried it with the attribute selector still not working. I have also added a delay to make sure it has time to load, and also used waitForSelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well today it worked! I have no idea what was happening maybe the page had a bug?

this piece of code did it which I tried yesterday!

```
await page.click('#react-select-7-input');
await delay(wait_time);
await page.click('#react-select-7-option-2');
await delay(wait_time);
```